# RestKit mapping object with reference to id

Tags: ios5, mapping, restkit

I have an object *OrganizationalUnit* which is linked to parent entities through a *parentId* attribute. *OrganizationalUnit* has also a primary key attribute *ouId* (mapped from the JSON "_id" field).

This is my code:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *ouMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[OrganizationalUnit class] inManagedObjectStore:manager.objectStore];
[ouMapping mapAttributes:@"name",@"type", nil];
[ouMapping mapKeyPath:@"_id" toAttribute:@"ouId"];
[ouMapping setPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"ouId"];

[ouMapping mapKeyPath:@"parent" toAttribute:@"parentId"];

[ouMapping hasOne:@"parent" withMapping:ouMapping];
[ouMapping connectRelationship:@"parent" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"parentId"];
```

Which works the same way of the example found in RestKit:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* taskMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Task class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];
taskMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"taskID";
[taskMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"taskID"];
[taskMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
[taskMapping mapKeyPath:@"assigned_user_id" toAttribute:@"assignedUserID"];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:taskMapping forKeyPath:@"task"];

// Hydrate the assignedUser association via primary key
[taskMapping hasOne:@"assignedUser" withMapping:userMapping];
[taskMapping connectRelationship:@"assignedUser" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"assignedUserID"];
```

which should create locally a relationship between objects based on the ids.

Unfortunately at run-time, when the actual mapping of received data is happening, I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x6d9c6f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _id.'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the JSON that you're trying to map? I've had similar issues with RestKit and might be on to a solution (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054112/mapping-relationships-in-restkit-through-an-array-of-ids-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm getting to the root of the problem, probably caused by the children not able to reference the parents because they do not yet exist.