# RestKit 0.20.0 rc1 - Create request post with array of Strings

Tags: ios, ios6, request, restkit

is there a way to create arrays of Strings in requests?
I did found some solutions for response, but the most of them are restkit 0.10.x or I did not understand them. (for example [Mapping relationships in RestKit through an array of IDs doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054112/mapping-relationships-in-restkit-through-an-array-of-ids-doesnt-work))

This is my setting:
I use iOS 6 with core data and managed objects. My request should be like

```
{
 "attribute":["some text", "some more text", "and one more text"],
 "relationship":[some object data],
 "string":"some text"
}
```

The entity is called "doRequest". "Relationship" is a relationship to an other managed object and "string" is an attribute. I would like to have "attribute" as an attribute, but there is no way to set "attribute" to an array of strings. So "attribute" is an one-to-many relationship to an entity "sub attribute" with attribute "text".

My rest kit mapping:
    RKObjectMapping *subAttributeMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [subAttributeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"text"]];

```
RKObjectMapping *doRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[doRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"string": @"string"}];

[doRequestMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"attribute" mapping:subAttributeMapping];
[doRequestMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"relationship" mapping:relationshipMapping];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:doRequestMapping objectClass:[DoRequest class] rootKeyPath:nil];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

Restkit map this like:

```
{
 "attribute":[{"text":"some text"}, {"text":"some more text"}, {"text":"and one more text"}],
 "relationship":[some object data],
 "string":"some text"
}
```

But that's not what I need.
Could you please help me?

Comment: The request you would like to send isn't in a valid JSON format (see http://jsonlint.com). Perhaps trying to configure the content of the `attribute` before sending the object works?

Comment: The JSON was only just an example to show what I would like to do. So I know, that "some object data" is not a valid expression. ;-)
But thanks for your answer. I'm configuring my content before sending it like you did say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fixed it by using only objects without using core data.
My object now have a new attribute `NSArray *attributeArray` to restkit let create an array of strings.

My DoRequest.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface DoRequest : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * string;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * relationship;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *attribute;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *attributeArray;
@end

@interface DoRequest (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addRelationshipObject:(RelationshipReference *)value;
- (void)removeRelationshipObject:(RelationshipReference *)value;
- (void)addRelationship:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeRelationship:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addAttributeObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeAttributeObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addAttribute:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeAttribute:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

My DoRequest.m:

```
#import "DoRequest.h"
#import "RelationshipReference.h"
#import "Attribute.h"

@implementation DoRequest

@dynamic string;
@dynamic relationship;
@dynamic attribute;
@dynamic attributeArray;

- (NSArray *)attributeArray
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Attribute.h *object in self.attribute) {
        [array addObject:object.attributeName];
    }

    return [array copy];
}

@end
```

My object mapper looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *doRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[doRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"string": @"string",
 @"attributeArray": @"attribute"}];

[doRequestMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"relationship" mapping:[self relationshipReferenceObjectMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:doRequestMapping objectClass:[DoQueryRequest class] rootKeyPath:nil];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```