# Can't get RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher to match for deleting orphans objects

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have the following mappings:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *productionParametersPerEquipment = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:productionParameterMapping
                                                                                                 pathPattern:@"/api/rest/productionparameters/?equipment=:equipment_id"
                                                                                                     keyPath:@"objects"
                                                                                                 statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

and then I have:

```
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/api/rest/productionparameters/?equipment=:equipment_id"];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
    NSString *productionParameterID;
    if (match) {
        productionParameterID = [argsDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ProductionParameter"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier = %@", @([productionParameterID integerValue])]; // NOTE: Coerced from string to number
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES] ];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

However, whenever I call the following, it **never** matches, hence my orphans are never deleted. Any ideas?

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/rest/productionparameters/?equipment=%@",_equipment.identifier] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern matcher can not match against patterns in the query string of the URL. Anything in the query needs to be handled separately. You should pattern match against the URL path and then query and process the parameters if / when the pattern matches.

Note, this pattern matching limitation applies outside of the scope of the deletion processing too.

So, set your pattern to match to `/api/rest/productionparameters`. Once you get a match you want to get the `query` from the `URL`. You can then use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to split the query parameters into key value pairs and then process each pair till you find `equipment` and extract the `id`.

Incidentally, the pattern would never have returned you `[argsDict objectForKey:@"id"]` anyway because you set the pattern parameter to `equipment_id`.

---

Typed on iPad so check, you probably want to add some checks on array counts too...:

```
[objectManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/api/rest/productionparameters"];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
    NSString *productionParameterID;

    if (match) {

        NSArray queryItems = [[URL query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

        for (NSString *item in queryItems) {

             NSArray *keyValPair = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

             if ([keyValPair[0] isEqualToString:@"equipment"]) {
                 productionParameterID = keyValPair[1];
                 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ProductionParameter"];
                 fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier = %@", @([productionParameterID integerValue])]; // NOTE: Coerced from string to number
                 fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES] ];

                return fetchRequest;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about how to do this? I am fairly new to all this URL/Matching stuff.

Comment: I am trying to get this working once again... I was wondering if it is possible for when we are fetching the objects with the URL /api/rest/productionparameters (it will map to ProductionParameters objects), will addFetchRequestBlock compare only  ProductionParameters objects, or ProductionParameters's propertyMapping as well?

Comment: For example, in that page http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html, the airport example. If the Airport includes a mapping to all the Airplanes, could we check in the addFetchRequestBlock for Airplanes since the mapping of Airport will map its children via the addPropertyMapping?

Comment: ? The fetch request block only gets given the URL so that is what you can test. You can add whatever you want to the fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[URL relativeString]` instead of `[URL relativePath]`, as relativePath omits the query string.

RKPathMatcher `matchesPath:` with `tokenizeQueryStrings:YES` will insert the parameters into the passed dictionary.